# Java jtable non editable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I'm developing a project and I have a little problem that does not find a solution.

I have a jtable who writes the results to a database and I am not able to block the editing of cells.

I have the following code to pass the query:

```
BaseDados Ligacao = new BaseDados();
LigaBD = Ligacao.LigaBD();
String consulta="SELECT modalidade_id AS 'ID', modalidade_nome AS 'Nome' FROM modalidades";
resultado = Ligacao.ResultadoConsulta(LigaBD, consulta);
jTableListaMod.setModel(Tabelas.CriaModeloTabela(resultado));
```

And the next class to make the table model:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Tabelas {
    public static TableModel CriaModeloTabela (ResultSet resultado)  {
        try {
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = (ResultSetMetaData) resultado.getMetaData();
            int NumeroColunas= metaData.getColumnCount();
            Vector NomesColunas = new Vector();
            for (int coluna = 0; coluna < NumeroColunas; coluna++){
                NomesColunas.add(metaData.getColumnLabel(coluna+1));
            }
            Vector Linhas= new Vector();
            while(resultado.next()){
                Vector Linha = new Vector();
                for (int i = 1; i <= NumeroColunas; i++){
                    Linha.add(resultado.getObject(i));
                }
                Linhas.add(Linha);
            }
            resultado.first();
            return new DefaultTableModel(Linhas, NomesColunas);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried things like this:

```
public class NonEditableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    NonEditableModel(Object[][] data, String[] columnNames) {
        super(data, columnNames);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Your NonEditableModel should work. If not then you have a bug elsewhere and will want to create and show us a [mcve].

Comment: use java coding conventions, variables should start with a `lowercase`. it will make your code easy to read.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am now improved it. This code was when I started learning to program for the first time in school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return new DefaultTableModel(Linhas, NomesColunas);
```

You want to use your custom TableModel:

```
return new NonEditableModel(Linhas, NomesColunas);
```

Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your names are correct, other are not. Be consistent!!!

Comment: Thank you for the help!!! I got this way.

When the code and variabeis with capital letter I apologize. The code is old, I am now improved it. This code was when I started learning to program for the first time in school.